# How do i refer to a UIButton inside an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

This is the code i've tried modifying, to no avail every time:

```
(UIButton *)[colourButtonsArray objectAtIndex:2].text = @"Test";
```

I get an error of 'Request for member 'text' in something not a structure or union.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Call the correct method:

```
[(UIButton *)[colourButtonsArray objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Documentation Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:

If you just want to cast and access properties you can just add more parenthesis (although text is not an actual property):

```
((UIButton *)[colourButtonsArray objectAtIndex:2]).buttonType;
```

Comment: I thought that was right at first, but the trick is that text is not a property of UIButton. You need to setTitle:, not text.

Comment: @Gendolkari you're right, I've updated my answer and given you a +1

Comment: Oh, I just came up with the .text thing anyway as a test. It works with other properties now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid extra parentheses with casting, you can use method syntax instead of dot notation. However, in the case of a UIButton... you set a UIButton's text with `setTitle:forState:` method.